# jquery setting an attribute to input and textarea with on for newly added elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-on

```
$("input:text,textarea").attr("autocomplete","off");
```

What's the twist to have it work when new elements get added to the dom.
Affect input:text and textarea to apply this rule to newly added elements after the rule was executed on $(document).ready

this is the answer, although not that perfect.

```
$(function() {
$("body").on("focus", "input:text,textarea", function(){
if($(this).attr("autocomplete")!="off"){
$(this).attr("autocomplete","off");
}
});
});
```

thanks for all the downvotes..

Comment: yeah, many input type text and textarea, that as these weren't coded via html I'd rather use jquery instead

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is that the autocomplete  is not a valid  attribute for the input field.. It is added by the jQuery plugins .

You need to set the autocomplete to on and off using the plugin syntax for the jquery UI

Comment: great, how would this be done, all I get to code is: $("input:text,textarea").attr("autocomplete","off"); What's the necessary wrapper for it to be activated for new elements as well

Comment: As soon as the element is added to the DOM.. Assign the autocomplete to it  $('#newelementID').autocomplete()

Comment: yeah, just thought there might be a more dynamic way as there are plenty of input type text and textarea that load via different functions

Comment: Because lets say you have assigned an autocomplete to a textbox. Next on button click you add one more textbox.. Now if you do this $('input:text').autocomplete() . It will add the autocomplete to the already existing element too.. To avoid that you add this to only the newly added element or destroy the autocomplete to all the prviously added elements and and them all again by using $('input:text').autocomplete();